# How can I create a website menu to take me to other page headings?

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I have created a website using Notepad ++ with HTML5. I have 4 pages, all of which have a number of different headings on that page. I have created a drop down menu of the 4 pages, which some have sub lists for the heading on that page. How would I be able to link the pages so when the user clicks on the heading from the menu, it will take them to that heading on the corresponding page.

This is my list, but the sub headings don't work:

- Home Page

  The Internet

  - History

  HTML

  - History
  - Through the      ages
  - HTML or XHTML?

  CSS

  - History

Comment: Post your attempts, it'll make more likely that someone will help.

Comment: Google for "Site navigation using HTML"

Answer (score 1):

## Method 1: Using `select` and javascript

If you are using a `<select>` dropdown then, you can do this with Javascript as below

```js
function href(elem) {
  var value = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
  if ( value ) {
    window.location.href = value;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="home.html">Home Page</a>

<select onchange="href(this)">
  <option>Title</option>
  <option value="page1.html#h1">Page 1 - 1</option>
  <option value="page1.html#h2">Page 1 - 2</option>
  <option value="page1.html#h3">Page 1 - 3</option>
</select>

<select onchange="href(this)">
  <option>Title 2</option>
  <option value="page2.html#h1">Page 2 - 1</option>
  <option value="page2.html#h2">Page 2 - 2</option>
  <option value="page2.html#h3">Page 2 - 3</option>
</select>
```

Then, add a `id="h1"`, `id="h2"`, `id="h3"` to your page headings. The `#` after the page name links to the element with the same id. Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Html/html_links.asp)

Make sure you put the first snippet in a `<script>` tag

## Method 2: Using `details` and `a` tag

The HTML5 tag `details`-tag is a drop-down element and could be used for a menu. Example:

```css
/* Put in <style> tag */

details {
  cursor: pointer;
}
details div {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Some header</summary>
  <div>
    <a href="page.html">Some page</a>
    <br />
    <a href="page.html">Some page</a>
    <br />
    <a href="page.html">Some page</a>
  </div>
</details>
<details>
  <summary>Some header2</summary>
  <div>
    <a href="page.html">Some page2</a>
    <br />
    <a href="page.html">Some page2</a>
    <br />
    <a href="page.html">Some page2</a>
  </div>
</details>
```

Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_summary.asp)

## Method 3: Using CSS3

If you copy Lal's answer, and add a bit of CSS magic, you can create a simple dropdown. Safe [this](http://csswizardry.com/demos/css-dropdown/css/style.css) file to your server (or just use csswizardry's file url) and include the next code, you will get a nice dropdown

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yoursite.com/path/to/file/style.css" />
```

Or using the csswizardry's file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://csswizardry.com/demos/css-dropdown/css/style.css" />
```

You will get this:

```html
<!-- The css from csswizardry.com -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://csswizardry.com/demos/css-dropdown/css/style.css" />

<!-- Your menu, make sure you have "id='nav'" also included!-->
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="home_page.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="internet_page.html">The Internet</a>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="internet_history_page.html">History</a></li>  
     </ul>            
  </li>
  <li><a href="html_page.html">HTML</a>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="html_history_page.html">History</a></li>  
        <li><a href="ages_page.html">Through the ages</a></li>  
        <li><a href="html_or_xhtml_page.html">HTML or XHTML?</a></li>  
     </ul>            
  </li>
  <li><a href="css_page.html">CSS</a>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="internet_history_page.html">History</a></li>  
     </ul>            
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why javascript instead of using just an anchor tag..?

Comment: You can't add a `a`-tag to a select dropdown

Comment: He hasnt specified that he is using a select dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `<a>` tags inside `<li>` to create a Navigation bar as below.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="home_page.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="internet_page.html">The Internet</a>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="internet_history_page.html">History</a></li>  
     </ul>            
  </li>
  <li><a href="html_page.html">HTML</a>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="html_history_page.html">History</a></li>  
        <li><a href="ages_page.html">Through the ages</a></li>  
        <li><a href="html_or_xhtml_page.html">HTML or XHTML?</a></li>  
     </ul>            
  </li>
  <li><a href="css_page.html">CSS</a>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="internet_history_page.html">History</a></li>  
     </ul>            
  </li>
</ul>
```

See more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp)